# Samsung Series 3 laptop won't shut down?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, shutdown

It's been happening for a couple of days, but my laptop won't shut down or restart, it always says I'll lose work and asks to shut down anyway.

Even though I still click shut down, it doesn't.

Also, I can't turn the lock screen on. It won't work when I click <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which I manually have to do. My photos app doesn't work as well and also the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key won't work when I try to adjust the brightness but it works for sound.

Any ideas why & how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried forcing it off (hold the power button for 3-5 seconds)?

Comment: that worked thanks, thought it'd be something more complex but it just had to update more things ;~; my fn key still doesn't adjust my brightness though :l